# SQLAlchemy import errors in Pydev/Eclipse

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, pydev

I tried installing SQLAlchemy for Python 3.2 which I use with Eclipse/Pydev. A simple test script fails

```
from sqlalchemy.engine import create_engine
engine=create_engine("mysql://user:password@server/database")
```

If I run it from Eclipse I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "...\sqlalchemy.py", line 1, in <module>
    from sqlalchemy.engine import create_engine
  File "...\sqlalchemy.py", line 1, in <module>
    from sqlalchemy.engine import create_engine
ImportError: No module named engine
```

However I actually generated the import line with Ctrl-Shirt-O, so Eclipse found that automatically and knows about it. Also Pydev does not show any errors in the script.

If I try the same script in the interactive Pydev console I get

```
from sqlalchemy.engine import create_engine
engine=create_engine("mysql://user:password@server/database")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python32\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy-0.7.8-py3.2.egg\sqlalchemy\engine \__init__.py", line 338, in create_engine
    return strategy.create(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python32\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy-0.7.8-py3.2.egg\sqlalchemy\engine\strategies.py", line 64, in create
    dbapi = dialect_cls.dbapi(**dbapi_args)
  File "C:\Python32\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy-0.7.8-py3.2.egg\sqlalchemy\connectors\mysqldb.py", line 52, in dbapi
    return __import__('MySQLdb')
ImportError: No module named MySQLdb
```

Do you have an idea how to get it work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answer is simple: your main module is named `sqlalchemy.py`. This is a trap that was much more easier to fall in python 2 - naming your own module by the same name as a system module.

At startup your `sqlalchemy.py` is loaded by python as the `__main__` module, and when the first line runs, python reloads `sqlalchemy.py` as the module `sqlalchemy`; the second time the import line is run the python interpreter already finds `sqlalchemy` in `sys.modules`, but it does not contain the variable or module named `engine`.

For easy fix rename `sqlalchemy.py` to for example `satest.py`. For more complete solution, organize your code in packages.

Answer (score 1):

While the first error was an unfortunate mistake as explained by Antti I finally also solved the other issue. I didn't have MySQLdb installed which again requires a MySQL Server. Instead I have mysql-connector for which the correct syntax is

```
engine=create_engine("mysql+mysqlconnector://...")
```

I didn't see this while looking for quick test examples.